# handle 1dp line in high resolution screens..?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 1dp line between each table row,I am able to see those lines in low resolution screen's. But if I see the same thing in nexus 4 those lines are not visible ,how can I make those 1dp lines visible in high resolution screens, so that my design will be same in all resolutions.?

Comment: dp stands for device independent pixel, so the line should be visible independently of the resolution.

Comment: I am able to see the line in 480x800 ,Samsung S2 , but the same line I am not able to see in nexus 4

Comment: try to increase line height. and check if you can see it.

Comment: 1dp should  be 1 dp across all screens.. as @Ridcully said

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int ScreenHeight = display.getHeight();
int ScreenWidth = display.getWidth();

View view = (View) findViewById(R.id.view);
LayoutParams paramsView = new LayoutParams((int)(ScreenWidth * .01), LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
view.setLayoutParams(paramsView);
```

It will set the width of your View to 1% of the ScreenWidth... You can increase the perecentage or use ScreenHeight variable as per your requirement!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while since the question, but there are several ways to do this:

1) Make a dimension entry in dimens.xml at 1dp:

> ```
> <dimen name="oneDP">1dp</dimen>
> ```

2) Get the DisplayMetrics, and then multiply the number of pixels by density:

> ```
> DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
> activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
> float scaleFactor = metrics.density;
> ```

It's late, but this might help somebody in the future